# How to show my plugin in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

can any one help to solve a problem?
Just For example:
If I have one site wpnpl.com.np
I wannt to give access to the  files of a plugin like if they type
wpnpl.com.np/npl they will access the features of the plugin
How to do this???Any Idea

Comment: did you create 'npl ' folder on root ?

Answer (score 1):

First create plugin short code in your plugin core file

```
 function bartag_func( $atts ) {
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'foo' => 'no foo',
            'baz' => 'default baz'
        ), $atts, 'bartag' );
        return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
    }
    add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

After that create a page in wp-admin with slug npl and content with

[bartag foo="bar"]